# Передать данные/файл в другое приложение на Маке

Tags: c#, objective-c, macos, файлы, xamarin

Моя программа создаёт скрипт для стороннего приложения. Как можно сразу открывать этот скрипт в том приложении? И можно ли это сделать без использования файлов? Пишу в Xamarin, на C#, но любое решение на Objective-C применимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный рабочий вариант, который я нашёл, это записать данные в какой-нибудь файл и программно открыть его желаемым приложением. Класс *NSWorkspace* ([class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Desktop_Image_Dictionary_Keys)) помогает в этом:

```
NSString *data = @"Some data";
NSString *filename = @"Some filename";
[data writeToFile:path
       atomically:NO
         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
            error:nil];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:filename
                        withApplication:@"Graphviz"];
```

Для C# и Xamarin код такой:

```
using AppKit;
using System.IO;
...
string data = "Some data";
string filename = "Some filename";
File.WriteAllText (filename, data);
NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenFile (filename, "Graphviz");
```

Для работы без файла, вероятно, нужно, чтобы то приложение поддерживало AppleScript, чего нет.

Answer (score 1):

Для посылки сообщения в другое приложение существует NSDistributedNotificationCenter

Послать сообщение

```
NSString *observedObject = @"com.alexanderyolkin.myapp";
NSDistributedNotificationCenter *center =
[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center postNotificationName: @"xpcNote"
                      object: observedObject
                    userInfo: dict
          deliverImmediately: YES];
```

Слушать сообщения

```
NSString *observedObject = @"com.alexanderyolkin.myapp";
NSDistributedNotificationCenter *center = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver: self
           selector: @selector(callbackWithNotification:)
               name: @"xpcNote"
             object: observedObject];
```

В NSDictionary передаем все, что нужно